# Mysql join query using three tables

Tags: mysql

I'm using  three tables. In the first table are recorded customer questions.

```
  customer_id   |   question   | question_id
----------------------------------------------
       58       |   question 4 |      4
       41       |   question 5 |      5
       37       |   question 3 |      3
```

In the second table are recorded comments relevant to questions from the first teble

```
    comment   | question_id   |  user
---------------------------------------
    comment 1 |      4        |    41  
    comment 2 |      5        |    58         
    comment 3 |      4        |    41  
    comment 4 |      5        |    58  
    comment 5 |      3        |    23
```

In the third table are located data about the users of this site

```
    user      | status
--------------------------------
     58       |      1
     41       |      1
     37       |      0 
     23       |      0
```

How can I make a query that will result as a list of the last five questions sorted by question_id and the total number of comments related to each question. These questions and comments can be only by the users with the status "1" a third table.

The result in this example should look like:

```
  question   | total comments  |   user
-----------------------------------------------
 question 5  |      2          |    41
 question 4  |      2          |    58
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain this is correct, though I don't have the data here to validate.

```
SELECT questions.question, 
       count(comments.question_id) as 'total comments', 
       user.user
FROM user 
  JOIN questions on user.user = questions.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN comments on questions.question_id = comments.question_id
WHERE user.status = 1
GROUP BY comments.question_id,  questions.question, users.user
ORDER BY questions.question
LIMIT 5
```

The LEFT JOIN on questions will allow questions to be represented even if no comments have been left on them.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: as a result I get NULL in question column.

Comment: Using the exact tables in the question above?

Comment: Sorry Kevin. I did not put the proper names of the column when I tested your query. This time I tested it right and it doesn't count null values in comment table. This query counts only comments of the questions that have comments. Those questions without comment were not counted.

Comment: Ah - thanks for commenting. I did not realize you needed those.

Comment: Do you know how can I do that? What do I need to change in this query?

Comment: I've modified the query. I believe it should work now, though there may be typos in it as I don't have the tables here to test with.

Comment: Now everything works properly. Do you know how can I exclude from the number of comments per question users who have commented but in the table users they have status 0?

Comment: They should be excluded already. The `user.status = 1` portion should exclude questions and comments from users with status 0.

Answer (score 0):

Quick look at it and I would do this:

```
SELECT q.question_id, count(c.comment) from questions as q left join 
comments as c on q.question_id=c.question_id left join user as u on 
c.user=u.user where u.status=1 group by q.question_id
```

Comment: @cb0- it doesn't count null values in comment table

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT question, count(*) as total_comments, T1.user 
FROM T1, T2, T3
WHERE T1.customer_id = T3.user 
  AND T3.status = 1,
  AND T1.question_id = T2.question_id
GROUP BY T2.user 
ORDER BY question_id DESC
LIMIT 5
```

T1, T2, T3 are the tables in question in the order they are presented.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      question_id as question, count(c.comment) as 'total comments', q.customer_id as user
FROM        (SELECT * 
            FROM question
            ORDER BY question_id DESC
            LIMIT 5) as q LEFT JOIN 
            comment as c using(question_id) LEFT JOIN
            user as u using(user) 
WHERE       u.status=1 
GROUP BY    q.question_id
ORDER BY    question_id DESC
```